# Spring data redis zadd command missed nx|xx|incr options

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis, lettuce

Lettuce supported zadd's NX|XX|CH|INCR options on 2015 [link](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/74).

But I can't find any thing support this in Lettuce's wrapper Spring data Redis (version:2.1.5).

It seem that the only two zadd methods that DefaultZSetOperations provide can't let me use NX|XX|CH|INCR options:

```
Boolean add(K key, V value, double score);
Long add(K key, Set<TypedTuple<V>> tuples);
```

So how can I use NX|XX|CH|INCR options on Spring data redis with Lettue?

Sorry for my poor english ,Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure if this will 100% work the same for Lettuce. For Jedis, found that we have to use `redisTemplate.execute(RedisCallback)`. A small example of using the `ch` argument for indicating if any records where changed (opposed to just being added to the sorted set)

```
redisTemplate.execute(
  (RedisCallback<Long>) connection -> connection.zSetCommands().zAdd(
                        leaderboardKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                        membersToTuples(members),
                        RedisZSetCommands.ZAddArgs.empty().ch()
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I use script

```
    String script = "return redis.call('zadd',KEYS[1],'NX',ARGV[1],ARGV[2])";
    DefaultRedisScript<Long> redisScript = new DefaultRedisScript<>(script,Long.class);
    redisTemplate.execute(redisScript, Collections.singletonList(key),String.valueOf(score),value);
```